# How do I reuse a partial control across different Views, with different routes?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an ASP.NET MVC solution where i have a toolbar with a "create user" button.
I have several entities in my system where you can add/create a user. Depending on the entity you add a user to, the destination page is different. Fx.

I have a "Department" entity, when i add/create an user from that entity i need to go to the "EditDepartment" after creation.

When I am at the "Channel" entity and add/create an user from that entity I need to go to the "EditChannel" after creation.

I would like to reuse my "CreateUser" partial control, but how do I specify the destination after each creation - injection of a route? How is this done? I would like to avoid a monster "if" statement to determine the destination.

Comment: So are you calling the same action method when you add/create users from different entity pages?

Comment: You can pass the url you want to redirect after creation when you create the partial view in the parent.

Comment: @lopezbertoni how do you pass any data from view to controller without model binding?

Comment: You can pass a string/model to the Partial View that is not necessarily binded to the parent view. Please post some code to clarify the issue.

Comment: The View is bound to my ViewModel. E.g. EditDepartmentViewModel. Right now the Partial View has no ViewModel, because that would explode my models with small specific ViewModels.

Comment: Right now im not calling the same ActionMethod each time, thats the thing i want to fix, so that i can actually call the same ActionMethod with a parameter on how to save the user. That information should also contain the information on where to navigate from the Action method afterwards

Answer (score 0):

In each View where you place your CreateUser partial view, you can add a Hidden field to reference the Action you want to redirect. Then in your CreateUser Action you can get that field value from the Request

View

```
@Html.Hidden("Destination", "EditDepartment")
@Html.Partial("CreateUser")
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(UserViewModel viewModel)
{
    string destination = Request["Destination"];
    //Create logic...

    return Redirect(destination);
}
```

I don´t know if it's the best approach but is the first thing comes to my mind.